# The rationale behind academic and industry salary difference

Tags: industry, salary

This question is not about PhD students, but about professionals with PhD degrees. To narrow down the scope even further, let my subject be a computer science PhD seeking a job in Europe. (I'd include the USA as well, but I'm afraid the dynamics are not the same. However, feel free to include relevant comparisons and data in the answers when needed.)

The salary of such a professional, if they stayed in academia, will be probably lower than if they chose to get a job in industry.

What is the economic incentive behind the university policy to not have higher, more competitive salaries when compared to industry?

I know that state institutions are (at least partially) on the government budget, so they arguably have little say in the matter. However, private institutions are significantly more independent in their organization. Basically, isn't it in the institutions' best interest to have the "best pick" of PhD graduates, instead of competing against the lure of a higher pay?

Comment: Usually, academia is more research oriented. You are free to research _whatever pops in your mind_. Plus you can teach cool and modern topics to graduate students which is always a lot of fun. Such freedom is not present at the industry. So, many many people prefer the academic freedom even if salaries are a fraction of industrial ones.

Comment: Universities have less money.

Comment: Given how many people currently fight for each faculty position, we can be lucky that faculty salaries are still as high as they are.

Comment: To quote Dr. Raymond Stantz:  "Personally, I liked the university. They gave us money and facilities, we didn't have to produce anything! You've never been out of college! You don't know what it's like out there! I've WORKED in the private sector. They expect *results*."

Comment: Surely some also think teaching is important, and don't go to industry because there is less (no?) opportunity to teach.

Comment: @PsySp "You are free to research whatever pops in your mind"* well, only if you are a tenure awarded professor - any level below that you are more or less forced to do what you are told to do (by your supervisor or by whomever pays your scholarship).

Comment: @GennaroTedesco I am *not* a tenure awarded professor, and I spend the vast majority of my time researching whatever pops into my mind. Also, "supervisor" isn't really an accurate description of anyone above me in rank, and they definitely don't define my research agenda.

Comment: @Fomite This is great, but nevertheless you have to acknowledge that this isn't the general situation (at least not in every area).

Comment: @GennaroTedesco You were the one who asserted a general condition, not me.

Comment: @KevinMcKenzie It will be pretty hard to get hired, get tenure, get grants, get graduate students at a large research university without producing results. The real difference is that companies do not welcome risk. Or maybe I should not take ghost busters comments seriously..

Comment: @GennaroTedesco _forced to do what you are told_? I think you have a very distorted view of academia and our assertion couldn't be more false. I am not tenured (yet) and I was, and still am, free to do (80% of the time) any research that comes into my mind without having _anyone_ above my neck. Moreover, it seems that this is the norm: All the PostDocs we have they pursue their own research agenda, as well as the tenured track assistant professors. I do not know where your idea is coming from.

Comment: Are universities in Europe for-profit? All of the institutions with which I have worked (R-1 and teaching, all in the US) have tried to pay faculty as much as they can, but just aren't as flush with cash for payroll as (successful) private sector tech companies.

Comment: @JeffE Isn't that a matter of perspective? Sure, *some* universities have less money compared to *some* companies, but it also goes the other way. I think this is a rather large spectrum. But, what strikes me as important is also the income to number of employees ratio, where I think the universities are better off. Universities have around a few thousand faculty + admin stuff, companies can have tens or even hundreds of thousands of employees, but the income is not multiplied with the same scale. As an example, on the far side admittedly, compare employees vs income of Harvard and Microsoft.

Answer (score 25):

I highly doubt university salary policies are based on "economic incentive", especially in European countries where universities are directly funded by the ministry of education. Generally, political, not economic reasons prevail.

That aside, competition for academic positions is already fierce - there is simply no need to offer higher salaries to attract candidates. Currently, candidates are attracted by reputation, the thirst for knowledge, and similar non-monetary considerations. It is by no means clear that higher salaries would attract better candidates: you would have to argue that someone who simply follows the money would make a better researcher than someone who is willing to put in long hours at low pay for the dream of someday being allowed to put "Prof. Dr." in front of their name!

Comment: Good answer.  Certainly,  a _maître de conférences_ in France is probably much more prestigious for a young and good researcher after the PhD than any industrial job, especially in maths etc. Even if the salary is tiny in comparison to what someone could get e.g. in an investment bank etc.

Comment: Good answer. However, it is not just "following the money" vs "dreaming to be called Prof. Dr.". I'd argue that the main reason why competition for academic jobs is fierce is that there are way too many PhDs for each professor job opening. And many PhD's don't leave their field because they do not have the skills to work elsewhere. If my reasoning is correct, computer science professors in private institution should receive competitive salaries. Anybody who can comment?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65701/discussion-on-answer-by-nengel-the-rationale-behind-academic-and-industry-salary).

Answer (score 4):

A few thoughts on the disparity between academic and private industry salaries:

1. **In some cases, they aren't**: It's hard to get broad level comparisons as many companies are fairly cagey with their salaries and it's not something people often talk about, and there's a difficulty in a 1:1 correspondence between academic positions and industry ones, but I've talked to enough people to be comfortable saying that while industry positions *often* pay more, this isn't *universally* true.
2. **Universities aren't a free market**: Often, universities have salary guidelines set by the legislature if they're public, different compensation schemes to promote people trying for full professor, other constraints, etc. that mean their salary determination is not just "What the market can bear."
3. **They may not need to**: Getting a PhD is already something of an ode to opportunity costs, and there's a fairly heavy selective pressure towards people not necessarily being fully motivated purely by the number on their paycheck. For example, while financial considerations came up in my own job search, they were on the level of "This needs to not be a financial disaster for me to take the job" not "Coming in at a higher salary is what will determine my choice". That means offering more money may not actually yield better recruitment prospects.
4. **Academic freedom**: By and large faculty members have a considerable amount of autonomy over their research agendas, and are free to switch those agendas in a way that industry researchers are not. For example, if a drug company abandons working on drugs to treat X, it doesn't matter how interested you are in X, that's not what you're working on anymore. That freedom (which is, admittedly, constrained by things like "Can I get funding for X?") is valuable to people.
5. **Other soft factors**: Some people *like* being professors. I set my own hours, and if I want to not come into the office one day, and work from 10 PM to 5 AM on something, I'm fully free to do so in a way most people in private industry are not. I am, by and large, not directly supervised by anyone. Even when I was a postdoc, and had a direct supervisor, what I did with my day was mostly up to me.

Especially in fields where there is not a lot of movement between academia and industry (for example, in biomedical fields, leaving academia often means its hard to come back), one could view the higher industry salary as what has to be paid in order for people to give up the largely non-monetary "perks" of academia.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about other countries, but in Germany, you will have some other benefits from staying in academia (at least if you can get a position as a professor) that you will not have in the industry (google "Verbeamtung" for more details). One of them is the security that your company (the university) will not suddenly decide to fire, replace or transfer you, so you can be rather sure that you will have this job for the next 40-something years; something that might be nice for long time planning. There are other benefits, like health benefits, etc. - if you are interested in that feel free to google it.

So you have to decide between possible high income, but with risks, or lower (but still quite good) income that is rather secure.

That is, of course, only one reason. There might be many different reasons to go into industry or academia, there might be as many as there are people in both areas, but as you explicitly mentioned the money, I think risk vs. security might be a big point to make up for this gap in payment.

Comment: *so you can be rather sure that you will have this job for the next 40-something years* – If you ignore the fact that there almost no permanent positions in academia below the level of professor.

Comment: @DirkLiebhold "So you have to decide between possible high income, but with risks, or lower (but still quite good) income that is rather secure." https://www.hochschulverband.de/fileadmin/redaktion/download/pdf/w-portal-d/w1-besoldung_ful-beitrag.pdf here they say that an assistant professor has 3.667,98 Euro per month, after a basic tax calculation, that is around 2200 Euro. I don't know if this is "quite good". Perhaps I just don't have enough perspective...

Comment: @user3209815 2200Eu sounds a bit low for me for an Assistant Professor. Are you sure this is right? But again: people that stay in academia _they do not do this for money_.

Comment: @PsySp: The salary tables in question are for a special class of civil employee in Germany called *Beamte.* The salary is so low, because it comes with an automatic pension and other benefits. I earned almost as much as the listed salary on a part-time PhD position in Germany (not being in said class).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thanks for the explanation. That salary seemed too low for me to be on a "normal" scale.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thanks for bringing some scale to the discussion. I'm familiar with the term Beamte (I attended a Gymnasium in Germany), but aren't all professors Beamte? If not, could you share a similar salary scale for non-Beamte professors? And by professor, I mean from Juniorprofessor and up.

Comment: *but aren't all professors Beamte?* – Sure, but what what point do you want to make?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Your previous comment led me to believe that there are other classes of salaries for "non-Beamte" professors. Since you state that the low salary is for a "special class of civil employee" and that you used to earn "almost as much as the listed salary on a part-time PhD position", I was under the impression that not all professors are bound to that scale. That is why I asked whether there are other pay scales.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: more money does not in general buy better researchers.**

Your question is based on the premise "more money buys better researchers than less money". I would like to argue that, aside from the obvious fact that more money costs more money and therefore comes at the expense of other things, the premise itself is simply incorrect (I mean it is not *universally* correct; there are specific contexts when it is correct however).

The thing is, different kinds of people are motivated by different things. Some people are highly motivated by money and less by a passion for some specific professional calling. You can find a lot of them in finance and other very lucrative industries that are not known for being especially exciting. Other people are highly motivated by the passion for doing something very creative and/or with a high potential for societal impact. Academics tend to be those sorts of people.

Now imagine what would happen if universities suddenly started advertising professor positions that paid $1M a year. What I think would happen is that a lot of money-driven people would suddenly decide that academia is a good place to build their careers, as opposed to, say, finance or tech. Some of those people are quite talented and would be able to build impressive resumes that enable them to get a share of those lucrative jobs, driving out some more passion-driven academics.

However, in the long run academia would suffer. To do really good science, you have to have a great deal of passion - more than some of the money driven types would be able to muster for long term success or for making groundbreaking, world-changing discoveries (as opposed to just for building a good enough resume to land a tenure track job).

My example is a bit exaggerated, but it illustrates a general principle that I firmly believe is true: by offering less money than industry on average, universities not only save money, they actually select for a particular kind of person, who is in fact a better kind of researcher for fulfilling the mission academia is trying to accomplish.

Comment: *"more money does not in general buy better researchers"* it does not buy better researchers but it does buy better research -just simply because researchers wouldn't have to apply for new positions every 6 months, work with limited laboratory tools, give up on visiting conference and interrupt their research whenever no (or not enough) money is offered by university. We all agree that you don't do research for the money but practically speaking money does allow you to perform good research without worrying every 3 months.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco "work with limited laboratory tools, give up on visiting conference and interrupt their research whenever no (or not enough) money is offered by university." - You seem to be suggesting that higher paid industry scientists are using their higher salaries to support their research. I very much doubt this is true. Additionally, higher salary costs would eat into grant budgets and startup funds, and actually *reduce* the resources available for actual research.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Additionally, your "not having to worry every 3 months" is an argument against *short term* positions, not academic vs. private positions. I know plenty of consultants who are in a constant state of searching for jobs (either internally with projects as funding comes and goes or with different firms).

Comment: @Fomite I am not suggesting that people in industry use their salaries to support their research, I am stating that lack of money in the university does affect research as it cuts down the stability of the people who are involved in it. Moreover, you might be surprised but startups funds are in general way more than what university allowances are in the course of, say, 2-3 years (standard post-doc position duration). About my assumption on the short terms position, you're right, I am assuming that academic position are short (after all, are they not?).

Comment: @GennaroTedesco "I am assuming that academic position are short (after all, are they not?)" Not necessarily, no, and not inherently less than private industry positions.

Comment: @Fomite Well, except they are. What is the average duration of the sort of academic position you are referring to? In industry (unless you are dismissed) you are generally employed permanently. Don't take this wrong, I am not arguing that industry is better than academia, I am arguing that academia does in general pay way less and offers way less job stability.

Comment: "In industry (unless you are dismissed) you are generally employed permanently." - That's a **big** unless, given you can be fired for cause, laid off, the company goes under, etc. And I'd assert that the average duration of an academic position (lets say an average of 4, falling between a postdoc and non-tenured professor who doesn't get tenure) is quite a bit longer than many of the people I know who went into consulting had - as mentioned, there are many private industry positions where you must compete for projects internally or find yourself out of a job.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco According to the Bureau of Labor Statistics in the U.S., the median current job longevity for workers 25-34 is 3.2 years, which isn't meaningfully longer than most academic positions in the same age. Overall, it's 4.6, which is still...not that much longer, if at all.

Comment: @Fomite I can speak about Europe where there are very strict conditions around terminations and job security is extremely high. I don't know why you are talking about consulting (which is only one of the many jobs in industry); moreover, about the statistics you mention, one must see what they really mean. It may be true that people switch jobs very often but that might as well be because they want to (or because they get better jobs), not because the grant is over and they have to re-apply somewhere around the continent.

Comment: Don't assume everywhere is US (where employment is at daily will and academic positions are generally well paid): elsewhere (especially in Europe) academics positions are rare nowadays whereas industry employs decently well (and pays longer and better).

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Because if one is making statements about "industry" as a whole, one of many jobs in industry is still relevant, especially given its where a great many people in my field would end up if they went private. I'll note *I haven't* assumed the U.S. is everywhere - you're the one whose spoken in universality. I've simply asserted "That's not necessarily true..."

Comment: Had to -1 because the logic doesn't really work out.  Sure, if you offer tons of money, you'll get tons of applicants; but there're plenty of ways to ensure that you get true performers rather than frauds who just want the money.  And besides this logical mistake, there's the factual mistake that universities already _do_ offer more money when they want the best talent.

Comment: @Nat thanks for the feedback. You're free to disagree of course, but, to clarify: (a) I never said the money-driven people are "frauds" or that they would not be "true performers". They would be good researchers overall, but nonetheless I'm arguing that those kinds of people are not the ideal people universities want to attract. (b) I agree with your second point: universities sometimes offer more money when it makes sense to do so, and that's consistent with my answer (specifically, the part where I said there are contexts when the premise that more money buys better researchers is correct).

Answer (score 0):

Do not think that salaries in academia are low or fixed. Getting a good salary in academia is definitely more difficult and takes a lot longer than in industry. Basically anyone below a professor is not paid what he/she is worth. But then, the dynamics work quite a bit differently. As others have pointed out the number of people applying for academic positions is much higher than the number of positions. Especially at prestigious institutions. Once you reach a professor position, your salary depends highly on which country you are in. The span for tenured position salaries in Europe ranges from about 30k€ per year to 500k€. Though the latter is only possible if you are at the level of a Nobel laureate.